# Angularfire2 - Access object values

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

In my code I have something like

```
this.users = firebase.database.list("/users");
```

which I can access in the HTML Code like:

```
<tbody *ngFor="let user of users | async" >
      <tr >
        <td>
          {{user._name}}
        </td>
      </tr>
```

which works great. But how I can I access this the `_name` variable for example in the native JS code? I would always get errors that the variable does not exist.

Comment: post your code here for which you get error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this

`this.users = firebase.database.list("/users");`

you can do this:

`firebase.database.list("/users").subscribe(users => this.users = users);`

Now you have access to the users array in your controller.

In your template you should also remove the `async` pipe.